# How to accept parameters via submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to save parameters sent by different submit button each time so that I can distinguish if it's published or just saved.

In my view,

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
...
<%= f.submit 'Draft', name: "status", value: "draft" %>
<%= f.submit 'Publish', name: "status", value: "publish" %>
<% end %>
```

When I submit with "draft" button, I got parameters as follows

```
"post"=>{"title"=>"bar", "body"=>"foo"},
"status"=>"draft",
"controller"=>"posts",
"action"=>"create"}
```

My controller

```
def new
 @post = Post.new
end

def create
 @post = Post.new(post_params)
 if @post.save
   redirect_to @post
 else
   render 'new'
  end
end

private
 def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body).merge(:status, params[:status])
end
```

Then I got errors,

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

What did I do wrong, and how do I pass draft/publish parameters to save in a database?

Comment: you might want to post your "Post" model and a dump of the post_params as they return from the strong_parameters function

Comment: Why not just have a f.hidden_field :status and have f.buttons instead of f.submit. Using javascript you can easily put the right value in the hidden field. I think that would be more elegant than using two submit buttons with the same name/id, which might produce unwanted results.

Answer (score 0):

.merge takes only one argument, which is where the wrong number of arguments error is coming from. Try merging just params[:status].